# Distinguish between "fundamental" ctypes data types and subclasses thereof?

Tags: python, parameter-passing, ctypes, dllimport

## Introduction

I am working on a code generator that would generate functions around `ctypes.cdll` loaded functions. The generator would take information about the `ctypes` of the arguments and the return value, and generate something that behaves (and, to some extent, looks) like this:

```py
func = getattr(dll, 'UglyLongAndUselessCName')
func.argtypes = [ctypes.c_uint32, ctypes.c_int8, ctypes.c_char_p]
func.restype = ctypes.c_int16

def nice_python_name(handle: int, arg1: int, arg2: str) -> int:
    return func(handle, arg1, arg2)
```

Notice how python type annotations play nicely with the `ctypes` data types of the function arguments. Also notice that there is no conversion code between the python types in `nice_python_name` function and `func` function. This is what my question is about.

## Getting close to the problem

The `ctypes` docs say that if the `argtypes` attribute of a loaded DLL function is specified using "fundamental data types", then when calling the loaded DLL functions, `ctypes` will do the conversion to python types for you. This is great, because in this case my generated code will look like the example above - I won't need to explicitly convert `ctypes` objects to python-typed values for returned values, and the reverse for the arguments.

However, the docs also say that for "subclasses of the fundamental data types" this trick will not work, and calling a loaded DLL function will require `ctypes` objects for arguments, and the result will be a `ctypes` object.

This is the excerpt from [the `ctypes` docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/ctypes.html#ctypes-fundamental-data-types-2) about it:

> Fundamental data types, when returned as foreign function call results, or, for example, by retrieving structure field members or array items, are transparently converted to native Python types. In other words, if a foreign function has a `restype` of `c_char_p`, you will always receive a Python bytes object, not a `c_char_p` instance.
>
> Subclasses of fundamental data types do not inherit this behavior. So, if a foreign functions `restype` is a subclass of `c_void_p`, you will receive an instance of this subclass from the function call. Of course, you can get the value of the pointer by accessing the value attribute.

So, I would like to get around this.

It seems that I need to know if a type is "fundamental" or a "subclass". This will help me define the way the code is generated, i.e. for "fundamental" types the generated code would look similar to the above example, and for "subclasses of fundamental" types it will have the extra conversion from `ctypes` objects into reasonable python types (or the generator will just throw an exception saying "this is not supported").

## Question:

#### How can I distinguish between "fundamental `ctypes` data types" and "subclasses of fundamental `ctypes` data types"?

I looked into the code of `ctypes` python module and discovered that both `c_void_p` and `c_char_p` are subclasses of `ctypes._SimpleCData`, hence one is not a subclass of the other in any way.

Also, do I misunderstand it that this problem also applies to the input arguments, or is this only the deal for the returned values?

Answer (score 2):

> ... do I misunderstand it that this problem also applies to the input arguments, or is this only the deal for the returned values?

It does not apply to input arguments, as the sequence below shows:

```
>>> dll=CDLL('msvcrt')
>>> dll.printf.argtypes = c_char_p,
>>> dll.printf(b'abc') # Note: 3 is the return value of printf
abc3
>>> class LPCSTR(c_char_p): # define a subtype
...  pass
...
>>> dll.printf.argtypes = LPCSTR,
>>> dll.printf(b'abc')
abc3
```

Conversions still work for input subtypes; however, output subtypes work differently as your doc quote mentioned:

```
>>> dll.ctime.argtypes = c_void_p,
>>> dll.ctime.restype = c_char_p
>>> dll.ctime(byref(c_int(5)))
b'Wed Dec 31 16:00:05 1969\n'
>>> dll.ctime.restype = LPCSTR
>>> dll.ctime(byref(c_int(5))) # not converted to Python byte string
LPCSTR(1989707373328)
>>> x = dll.ctime(byref(c_int(5))) # but can get the value
>>> x.value
b'Wed Dec 31 16:00:05 1969\n'
```